# docker container in windows when only used to working on linux computers

Tags: windows, docker

I am trying to processing some imaging data in windows using docker.  My problem is that I have only worked like this in linux and I keep running into issues where the path can't be found.  I am sure there is a simple solution to this, but I can't figure out what this is.

In windows power shell if I type...

cd \cmvm\users\c - I go straight there

If I type docker run dcm2bids \cmvm\users\c   -  "file not found in $PATH: unknown".  What obvious thing am I don't wrong.  Please help, this should be such a simple solution but I keep running into this stupid path issue.

Comment: Your docker filesystem is completely separate from your host filesystem -- this is true in Linux as well as Windows. A local path isn't going to be available unless you explicitly expose it to the container (e.g., as a bind mount).

Comment: How does someone do this.  I've tried typing in... docker run -v  \\some_windows_dir\ dcm2bids      - the file doesn't yet do what it is supposed to do, but I do notice that it mounts this file???    Is there some clear documentation on this somewhere for complete novices?  I just want to run a simple run command to initiate running a docker image on a particular group of files in my windows computer.

Comment: From what I learned about the windows system, the windows file directory needs to be mounted on the linux side of WSL.  From what I can tell ONLY the c drive is mounted and you can not run a linux based docker command on a commaned line pointing to the windows side.  Not sure if there is a simple way around this problem?